# Array to string conversion ERROR in PHP JSON decoded array

Tags: php, json, error-handling, type-conversion

I'm new to PHP working on script to get JSON data from a URL I got the data from the URL and decoded that JSON also.

But issue is that the JSON decoded array is not converting into `String`. An error comes when I try to run in to `foreach` loop
here is that array example output:

Array name is: `$data`

OUTPUT:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(5) "world"
    [1]=> array(12) {
        [0]=> string(15) "worldstarhiphop"
        [1]=> >string(17) "world series 2014"
        [2]=> string(18) "world of solitaire"
        [3]=> string(9) "world map"
        [4]=> string(19) "world's tallest cow"
        [5]=> string(10) "world news"
        [6]=> string(12) "world series"
        [7]=> string(9) "worldstar"
        [8]=> string(12) "world market"
        [9]=> string(29) "worldstarhiphop official site"
        [10]=> string(19) "world's tallest dog"
        [11]=> string(17) "world of warcraft"
    }
}
```

I tried that:

```
if(is_array($data)) {
  foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Giving this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

Comment: `$data` is an array containing *both* strings and arrays.  So, in one iteration of the loop, `$value` is an array.

Comment: so what i can do to output that array each value?

Comment: Check if it's an array (`is_array`), then loop over it and print each element.

Comment: i already did though check my code

Comment: We already know `$data` is an array.  I was talking about `$value`.  Sometimes it's a string, sometimes it's an array.

Comment: so you asking to check the $value also is an array or not right?

Comment: Yeah.  That's the issue here.  `$data[1]` is an array.  Add `if(is_array($value))` and loop over `$value` if it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is always structured like that with `0` as a word and `1` containing an array of related words, then:

```
echo $data[0];

foreach ($data[1] as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help you get started. The var_dump is basicly for debugging showing you the contents of the variable.

```
foreach($data as $foo) {
  if(is_array($foo) {
     foreach($foo as $bar) {      
       var_dump($bar);
     }
  } else {
    var_dump($foo);
  }
}
```

Consider that this could also be solved in a recursive fashion.

```
function printNestedArray($foo) 
{
  if(is_array($foo) === false) {
    var_dump($foo);
  } else {
    foreach($foo as $bar) {
      printNestedArray($bar);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this first it made it too much load also it shows "String(No of string in here)" also it return as one string and it's not able to be printed separately too?

Comment: Change the `var_dump` to `echo` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @AbdullahSiddique, I am not always a big fan of giving the answer out straight, sorry bout that, luckly AbraCadaver has made a pretty concise answer. I am curious, what you mean by "too much load", unless you have a really big array, I would not spend any time on performence.

Comment: Thanks both alot :) I'm new to this and still learning the surface :)